# ManyToMany realtion in Hibernate doesn't work properly

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I want to make relation Many-To-Many between two classes.
I have classes like this - "Room":

```
@Entity
public class Room {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long number;
private boolean state;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roomList")
private List<Exhibition> exhibitionList;

public Room(){

}

public Room(int number, boolean state) {
    super();
    this.number = number;
    this.state = state;
}

...getters and setters...
```

And class "Exhibition":

```
@Entity
public class Exhibition {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long Id;
private String title;
private Date dateOfOpening;
private Date dataOfEnding;
private double price;
private String description;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="EXHIBITION_ROOM")
private List<Room> roomList;

public Exhibition(){

}

public Exhibition(String title, Date dateOfOpening, Date dataOfEnding, double price, String description) {
    super();
    this.title = title;
    this.dateOfOpening = dateOfOpening;
    this.dataOfEnding = dataOfEnding;
    this.price = price;
    this.description = description;
}

...geters, setters...
```

I tried to do relation ManyToMany. I took an example from JPA 2.1 JavaDoc in Hibernate documentation, and it didn't work (It created empty table "EXHIBITION_ROOM" with no id inside). Every other relation like OneToOne works normaly, also inheritance. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but you're only telling the `roomList` to be joined by a table, not how to do it.
Look at this example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/ManyToManyJoinedTable.htm)

Specifically at:

```
@ManyToMany 
@JoinTable(name="EMP_PROJ", 
      joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="EMP_ID"),
      inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="PROJ_ID"))
```

E.g. in addition, you need to specify the IDs on which to link the two entities.
In your case it will be something like

```
@JoinTable(name="EXHIBITION_ROOM", 
joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="EXHIBITION_ID"),
inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ROOM_NUMBER"))
```

Not sure about the names, as I don't know the names of your tables. But give this a try, maybe play around with the names a bit as well.